# Qunit Location.reload() function is trigger again and again..?

Tags: javascript, jquery, unit-testing, user-interface, qunit

I am working on button event called clear, this button will reload the page when ever it clicks:

```
var buttons = {
    clearbtn: function (e) {    
        location.reload();
    }
};
```

Here is my test code:

```
test('Clear button test case', function () {
    var $clear = $('#clearbtn');
    var callcount = 0;
    location.reload = function () {
        debugger;
        console.log(callcount);
        callcount++;
    };

    $clear.trigger('click');
    ok(callcount === 1);
});
```

The `Qunit Page` is reloading again and again and my test case is not excuting at all?

Comment: Can you show us the QUnit HTML document?

Comment: here is my input html:-


<input type="button" id="btnClear" class="auditingClearBtn" name="btnClear" value="Clear" />

Comment: Sorry, I meant the HTML for the QUnit test file itself.

Comment: I have attached my test js file and my original file with qunit js and css file..!!! 

<h1 id="qunit-header">User Tests</h1>
    <h2 id="qunit-banner"></h2>
    <div id="qunit-testrunner-toolbar">
    </div>
    <h2 id="qunit-userAgent"></h2>
    <div id="test-content">
    </div>

    <ol id="qunit-tests"></ol>


 <div id="qunit-test-area">
    </div>
    <div id="qunit-fixture">
<input type="button" id="clearbtn" name="clearbtn" value="Clear" />
</div>

Comment: Sorry, but you can't really attach files in StackOverflow. Instead, please try updating your original post with the content of your QUnit HTML file, but not the "view source" version, I need to see the actual source code.